# Visual Studio Community 2013 prepends '_' to exported function names in dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I have the following definition in my MyLib.dll entry point cpp file:

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) SomeType* EntryPoint()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

When I run "dumpbin.exe /EXPORTS MyLib.dll" it returns:

```
ordinal hint RVA      name
1       0    000118CA EntryPoint = @ILT+1820(_EntryPoint)
```

Note the prepended '_'. I believe this is a problem because the host application is looking for "EntryPoint", not  "_EntryPoint". Using a def file does not help.

How do I force Visual Studio Community 2013 to not prepend the '_'?

Comment: *I believe this is a problem* You believe, or you're sure? Do you have link errors?

Comment: I do not get link errors. The host application scans for dlls with the proper export. It does not find the dll I built. Since the export function name is not identical to what the host expects, I *suspect* this is the problem. I won't know for sure until I can remove the underscore, which is really what my question is about: How do I remove the underscore?

Comment: The exported function name is `EntryPoint`. The `(_EntryPoint)` is just additional information provided by `dumpbin` to help you see what function it refers to. it does this as a courtesy. [The actual name being exported does not have the underline](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/13/10164020.aspx).

Comment: @Raymon Chen. If correct then this *is* the answer to the above question. Please answer as such. Thanks!

Comment: It's just a sketch of an answer. You can turn it into a real answer and accept it.